# Use of square roots when factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If asked to fully factor $3x^3-x$, is it better to answer $x(3x^2-1)$ or $x(x\sqrt3+1)(x\sqrt3-1)$?

In general, can you use square roots when possible when asked to (fully) factor something?

Comment: Yes as long as it's the square root of a constant, not the variable itself; this helps in finding the roots of the equation $P(x)=0$ for example where $P$ is the polynomial you factored.

Comment: In general, if you're asked to factor something, it means over the integers, unless otherwise specified. This is almost certainly true in any math class up to calculus.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is "it depends". Factoring over the integers or rationals is different from factoring over the real numbers. If it isn't made clear which one you're expected to work with, then the exercise is poorly worded.

Over the rationals and the integers, $x(3x^2-1)$ is as far as you can go. Over the real numbers, you can go all the way to $x(\sqrt3x+1)(\sqrt3x-1)$.

The safest thing to do if you encounter this is to ask your teacher (or look at the examples in your book), because they are the only one who can tell you what they expect.

Comment: Probably the word "fully" here seems to imply linear factorization, corresponding to the Fundamental theorem of Algebra

Comment: @nonstudent If you invoke the FTA, do you mean all the way to the complex numbers if needed?

Comment: You are correct in your answer.  Yes, I would interpret "fully" as going down to complex numbers.  But as far as I know, the word "fully" is not a terminological word (**I am not sure**).  So I think your answer is justified.

Comment: @nonstudent I read the word "fully" as just meaning "as far as it can be done _within this context_", where the meaning of "this context" is exactly the crux of my answer. The way I read it, "fully" is there to make the answer $3x^3-x$ incorrect. But you might be right instead. It's impossible to know.

Comment: @nonstudent: If that's what's intended, it would be clearer to phrase the problem as "Find the roots of..."